# "Zwischen 1 und 6": Sind die Randwerte mit gemeint, oder nicht?

Tags: word-usage

In elementaren mathematischen Texten wird oftmals das Wort "zwischen" verwendet, um einen Zahlenbereich zu bezeichnen.

Z.B. kann man bei einem gewöhnlichen Spielewürfel Zahlen "zwischen 1 und 6 würfeln". Ist diese Sprechweise so korrekt, sind also die Zahlen 1 und 6 in dieser Wendung inbegriffen?

Wenn in einem Mathebuch die Aufgabe steht: Wie groß ist die Wahrscheinlichkeit, eine Zahl zwischen 1 und 6 zu würfeln. Dann könnte man denken, dass die Zahlen 1,2,3,4,5,6 gemeint sind, die Wahrscheinlichkeit also 1 ist, oder dass nur 2,3,4,5 gemeint sind und die Wahrscheinlichkeit 4/6 = 2/3 beträgt.

Die erste Variante konnte ich an verschiedenen Stellen im Internet finden, z.B. http://www.mathematik-wissen.de/einstufiges_zufallsexperiment.htm oder https://www.mathebibel.de/sicheres-ereignis.

Allerdings sagt der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zwischen_innerhalb_inmitten_binnen) dass "zwischen" "eine Erstreckung von etwas **innerhalb** von zwei begrenzenden Punkten" bezeichnet. Somit dürften die Randzahlen dann nicht mit gemeint sein.

Welches ist also die korrekte Bedeutung, wenn man sagt "zwischen 1 und 6" und wieso?

Comment: Korrekt ist 2,3,4,5, aber das wird so oft falsch gemacht, das es mittlerweile kaum noch auffällt. Sogar sonst korrekte Mathematiker vertun sich da. Wenn die das aber mathematisch ausdrücken würden (in Formeln), dann nicht mehr. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Inkorrekt (nach Duden-Definition) bedeutet nicht wirklich inkorrekt. Das hat mit Häufigkeit der Verwendung des anderen Begriffes nichts zu tun. Die hier zu diskutierende Definition ist bloß vom Duden nicht erfasst worden, die gibt es aber. Das erkläre ich in meiner Antwort.

Answer (score 7):

### Bei [zwischen](https://dwds.de/wb/zwischen) sind die Grenzen inklusive

Dieses Präposition ist ein sehr altes Wort und hat deshalb auch sehr viele unterschiedliche Bedeutungen und Anwendungen (siehe obiger Link zu DWDS). Unter all diesen ist es auch ein **Verweis auf eine Zahl innnerhalb zweier Grenzwerte**.

Da es sich hier um Sprache und nicht um eine Formel oder gar eine Operand handelt, fehlt es an der nötigen Präzision, die man in einem mathematischen Kontext natürlich herstellen muss.

Diese fehlende Präzision führt dazu, dass es im sprachlichen Kontext unerheblich ist, ob die Grenzen einbezogen werden oder nicht. Bei folgender Aussage

> Wir kommen zwischen zwei und drei Uhr.

Kann es sogar sein, dass man schon kurz vor zwei oder erst kurz nach drei eintrifft, denn es wurde im obigen Satz nur ein grober Zeitrahmen angegeben.

Auch wenn es genauer sein muss wie hier:

> Es werden zwischen 10 und 15 Teilnehmern erwartet.

werden mindestens 10 Sitzplätze, aber nicht mehr als 15, erwartet. Die Grenzen sind selbstverständlich inkludiert.

Wir alle haben diese sprachliche Definition beim Kinderspiel gelernt:

> Nenn eine Zahl zwischen 4 und 9!

Es wurde uns schnell klar gemacht, dass sowohl die 4 als auch die 9 gültige Zahlen sind. Auch hier sind die Grenzen inkludiert.

Wenn es also genau darauf ankommt, dass die Grenzen **nicht** eingeschlossen sind, darf man sich nicht auf das Wörtchen *zwischen* alleine verlassen. Man würde also z.B. sagen müssen:

> Nenn eine Zahl zwischen 4 und 9, Grenzen nicht eingeschlossen.

oder viel besser:

> Nenn eine Zahl, die größer als 4 und kleiner als 9 ist.

Comment: Und deshalb gibt es im mathematischen Kontext extra Konventionen, wann und ob eine Bereichsgrenze dazu gehört oder nicht: eckige Klammern [] und runde Klammern ().

Comment: @IQV An die Klammern hab ich nicht gedacht. Das ist in der Tat ein guter Beitrag!

Comment: Die Variante mit runden Klammern kannte ich nicht, mir sind sowohl in der Schule als auch im Studium nur die *auswärts gerichteten* eckigen Klammern begegnet, also [4;9] wenn die Grenzen eingeschlossen sind und ]4;9[ wenn sie nicht dazugehören.

Answer (score 2):

Es ist wenig fruchtbar, die Bedeutung von Aussagen in fachsprachlichem Kontext aus dem Duden oder der 
Verwendung von Wörtern im Alltag herleiten zu wollen. Im Alltag kann man 5 auch mal gerade sein lassen.

Auf die standardsprachliche Bedeutung von *zwischen* ist in anderen Antworten ausführlich eingegangen 
worden. Die Frage bezieht sich aber auf mathematische Texte und das Problem besteht hier ganz klar in 
einem Mangel an fachsprachlicher Ausdrucksweise.

Mathematik ist wesentlich das Herstellen struktureller Klarheit. Jeder Versuch, dieses Ziel zu erreichen, 
ist von vorn herein zum Scheitern verurteilt, wenn nicht deutlich gesagt wird, wovon überhaupt die Rede ist.

Sehr deutlich wird der Unterschied zwischen Standard- und mathematischer Sprache an den 
mathematisch logischen Konjunktionen *und* und *oder* und standardsprachlichen Wörtern der Wortart 
Konjunktion. [siehe auch](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/50155/36196)

Ob die Grenzen eines Intervalls eingeschlossen sind oder nicht, kann von Bedeutung sein. Ist das der Fall, 
muss das in mathematischen Texten ausdrücklich unterschieden werden. Auch wenn es nicht von 
Bedeutung ist, wird ein Mathematiker das i.d.R. begründen. Es spielt zum Beispiel keine Rolle, ob die 
Ober- oder Untergrenze eingeschlossen ist, wenn für alle Werte die Wahrscheinlichkeit des Auftretens 
Null ist und es ausschließlich um zufällige Verteilung geht.

In der Praxis werden ein- oder ausgeschlossene Intervallgrenzen beispielsweise häufig durch 
unterschiedliche Klammern gekennzeichnet.

**[0,1]** 0 und 1 sind eingeschlossen

**[0,1[** oder **[0,1)** 0 ist eingeschlossen, 1 ist ausgeschlossen

Bei jeder Auswahl von Elementen aus einer Menge muss diese Menge eindeutig bestimmt sein. Das 
Beispiel aus der Frage zeigt es ja deutlich. Die in der Frage erwähnten Internetseiten geben eindeutig 
die Ergebnismenge an und schließen damit jeden Zweifel darüber aus, was mit **zwischen** gemeint ist.

> Wenn in einem Mathebuch die Aufgabe steht: Wie groß ist die Wahrscheinlichkeit, eine Zahl zwischen 1 und 6 zu würfeln.

... ist das Mathebuch ohne weitere Angaben ein Fall für den Mülleimer, sofern es sich nicht um ein Beispiel 
zur Verdeutlichung der Notwendigkeit präziser Ausdrucksweise handelt. Die Antwort könnte lauten: *Beim 
Blackjack ist die Wahrscheinlichkeit Null.*

**Ohne weitere Angabe kann davon ausgegangen werden, dass alle möglichen Ergebnisse inbegriffen sind. 
Warum sollten die 1 und die 6 ausgeschlossen sein?** Die Wahrscheinlichkeit hängt dann von der Anzahl 
der Würfel ab. Mit einem einzigen Würfel ist das Ergebnis mit Sicherheit eine der Augenzahlen aus der 
Menge {1,2,3,4,5,6} und die Wahrscheinlichkeit damit 1. Mit zwei oder mehr Würfeln ist die 
Wahrscheinlichkeit für das Ergebnis 1 gleich Null ... Oder sollte am Ende in Wahrheit gemeint sein, wie 
groß die Wahrscheinlichkeit für jedes der möglichen Ergebnisse ist?

Answer (score 1):

> Allerdings sagt der Duden dass "zwischen" "eine Erstreckung von etwas innerhalb von zwei begrenzenden Punkten" bezeichnet. Somit dürften die Randzahlen dann nicht mit gemeint sein.

Ganz so klar sagt das der Duden nicht!

Je nach Situation können die Endpunkte mitgemeint sein.

Dies wird meist geklärt mit der Formulierung “von ... bis” bzw. “von ... und bis mit” oder “ab .. bis”

Bei den Augen eines Würfels ist der Fall klar.

Bei Terminen und Altersangaben könnte die Angabe mit  “zwischen” tatsächlich Verwirrung stiften.

Comment: Ich würde sagen: eigentlich nicht, aber das wird oft falsch benutzt.

Comment: Der Punkt ist wohl der: wenn es z. B. heisst, zwischen 14 und 25 werde am meisten gekifft,  dann sind die 14 Jährigen mit gemeint ...

Comment: Ja, dann sind die mit gemeint, aber da wird "zwischen" einfach falsch benutzt. Das wird zwar oft gemacht, ist aber formal immer noch falsch.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Wieso denn? Meiner Meinung nach ist die Aussage unabhängig von der Interpretation von "zwischen" zulässig. Ein 14,001-jähriger gehört zur Gruppe der Personen zwischen 14 und 25. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass jemand genau 14 Jahre alt ist, beträgt mathematisch null!

Comment: Ganz einfach: *zwischen* ist immer exklusiv der Begrenzung. Das gilt für Autos die zwischen Bäumen parken, oder Geschäfte die zwischen zwei Seitenstraßen stehen, usw. Also gerade Zahlen zwischen 1 und 6 sind immer 2, 3, 4 und 5. Aber es ist bekannt, dass das oft falsch benutzt wird, und Leute *eigentlich* eins bis einschließlich sechs meinen.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Also auch wenn der Kommentar schon über ein halbes Jahr alt ist, hier eine Anmerkung. Gerade Zahlen zwischen 1 und 6 sind nur 2 und 4. Die Zahlen 3 und 5 sind ungerade Zahlen.

Answer (score 1):

Ja, das ist zweideutig.

Während *von - bis* den einschließenden Sinn präzise wiedergibt, fehlt ein passendes Wort für den ausschließenden Fall. Ein mathematisches Lehrbuch könnte daher versuchen, *zwischen* als Gegensatz zu *von - bis* zu definieren, ohne das ausdrücklich zu kennzeichnen. Praktisch wird z.B. die [Notation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervall_(Mathematik)#Verallgemeinerung) [1,6], bzw. ]1,6[ oder gemischt [1,6[ gerne verwendet.

Die Definition aus dem Duden ist wenig hilfreich, da *innerhalb* nicht einfach für *zwischen* eingesetzt werden kann. Selbst im Fall *zwischen den Grenzen X, Y* ist nicht klar, wo die Grenzen nun genau liegen, da Grenzen typischer einen abstrakteren Typ haben als die Auswahl elemente, *die Grenze zwischen Deutschland und Dänemark*, *innerhalb der Grenzen Deutschlands*, zumal die Grenzen oft verschmiert, schwammig (English "fuzzy") sind, etwa *200 Meter von der Küste entfernt*, wobei die Küste keine klare Linie ist nach Benoit Mandelbrot sogar unendlich lang. Jedoch, wenn man sich *zwischen etwas* entscheiden muss, schließt das die Grenzen offensichtlich ein.

An *zwischen etwas* sieht man auch, das *zwischen* als Präposition für eine Einheit verstanden wird. Wäre die Präposition assoziativ auf beide Elemente einzeln anzuwenden *(zwischen (eins und sechs)) = zwischen eins und zwischen sechs*, würde das nur *bei*, *neben*, *hier* oder der gleichen bedeuten. Tatsächlich wird stattdessen *von - bis* verwendet. Analog dazu wäre etwa *nach - vor* denkbar. Meiner Erfahrung nach wird selbst für *von - bis* gerne *exklusiv* oder *inklusiv* dazu gesagt, bzw. [unnötiger Weise](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2009/05/07/bis-oder-bis-einschlieslich/) auch *von - bis einschließlich*.

Wieso das so ist? Weiß ich auch nicht genau, scheint relativ kompliziert zu sein.

Dafür sollte man vielleicht mal eine historische Forschung finden. Vergleichen ließen sich etwa *zu*, IE. *doh₁  und *zwei*, IE. *dwóh₁ bzw. *bis*, "bei+zu" und latein *bis*, IE. *dwís, griechisch *dia-* IE. *dwis-eh₂ mit *zwi-s-chen*, AHD *zwiska*, PGem *twisk(j)a vergleichen, sowie *beide*, En. *both*, PGem *bai- (IE. ?), und *bei*, englisch *by*, PGem *bi, IE. *h₁epi (woher auch *Abend*, *Epi-[Zentrum]*, etc.; Vgl. dazu auch *auf*, *oben*, *über*, **hepp!*, En. *up* und die Formulierung *von - über [bis]*). Bunt wird's erst, wenn ägyptisch *jmjtw* /imituː/ und *inmitten*, bzw. arabisch *bayna* hinzu gezogen werden. Eventuell ist auch Griechisch *kai edo* "für", *edo* "hier", IE. *do (etwa oben *doh₁?) relevant, sowie eher noch im Bezug zur Mathematik *durch* (etwas *durch* bzw. *für* vier teilen; Englisch *1 through 6* "1 bis 6"), PGem *þurhw, "*Likely from Pre-Germanic *tr̥h₂(h₃)kʷ-, a compound of Proto-Indo-European *terh₂- (“to cross”) + *h₃ekʷ- (“to see”). Others take the second element to be *-kʷe. In either event related to Sanskrit तिरस् (tiras, “through”), तिर्यञ्च् (tiryañc, “transverse, horizontal”)*", dabei ist *-kʷe die Wurzel zu dem oben genannten Gr. *kai*; Vgl. dazu auch Lat. *trans*<*tr̥h₂-n̥t-s<*terh₂-, *transport* (für *h₁ep war zu lesen "*... referring to pack animals or riding*"), vgl. wegen *-nt- auch *unter*, *nieder* (En. *nether regions*), demnach *Unter-Nehmung* (wieso *unter*, jetzt mal wirklich!?). Wenn man sich bei *unter* durchklickt, findet man auch IE. *h₁entér "between", daher *inter-* sowie *unter*, jenes allerdings "*conflated with *n̥dʰér (“under”)*", dazu steht "*Likely from *h₁ní (“down, downwards”) +‎ *dʰe (locative particle) ["where"]*". Tatsächlich erwähnt Pfeifer "ahd. untar zwiskēn":

> zwischen Präp. ‘innerhalb zweier (räumlicher oder zeitlicher) Begrenzungen, innerhalb einer Menge’. Aus adverbiell gebrauchten präpositionalen Verbindungen wie ahd. untar zwiskēn ‘unter, in der Mitte von zweien’, untar in zwiskēn ‘untereinander’ (9. Jh.), auch zusammengezogen untarzwiskēn sowie inzwiscōn, mhd. under, in zwischen, enzwischen entwickelt sich die einfache Form mhd. zwischen, zwüschen, (md.) zwuschen Adv. und Präp., mnd. twisken, twischen, mnl. tusscen, twussen, twisscen, nl. tussen. Auszugehen ist daher von einem Dativ Plural des sowohl distributiven wie kollektiven Zahladjektivs ahd. zwiski ‘zweifach, zu zweit, zweiteilig, abermalig’, Plur. ‘beide’ (8. Jh.), mhd. zwisc, zwisch ‘zweifach, je zwei’, Plur. ‘beide’, asächs. twisk ‘zweifach’, das germ. *twiska- bzw. *twiskja- voraussetzt; vgl. dazu auch aengl. betweoh, betwux, betwisc, engl. (älter) betwixt ‘dazwischen’. Es handelt sich um eine Bildung mit dem Suffix ie. -ko- zum Multiplikativadverb ie. *du̯is ‘zweimal’; s. dazu ↗Zwilling und ↗Zwirn. In bezug auf zeitliche Grenzen steht zwischen seit dem 14. Jh.
>
> [DWDS/zwischen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zwischen), <sub>Formatierung nicht übernommen</sub>

Wegen dem Niederländischen Vergleichsmaterial muss ich an *tauschen* und *täuschen* denken, die von unklarer Herkunft sind. *tauschen* wird zuweilen mit *trade* übersetzt, zu PGem. *trado "track, way" (Vgl. *etwas weggeben*), "*Proto-Indo-European *drā-, *der- (“to walk, step, run”). Cognate with Sanskrit द्राति (drāti, “to run”) and Ancient Greek δρόμος (drómos, “running”)*"; Vgl. dazu *tragen*, bzw. *heben*, IE. *keh₂p- "grab, seize", *hauen* *kewh₂- (*abhauen, abheben*; *Ausflug*; *Vorschlag*) zu *h₁epi, bzw. zu *h₂epó, denn bei der Gelegenheit sollte auch *von*, "*Proto-Germanic *afanē, *fanē, *funē (“from”), compound of *afa (from Proto-Indo-European *h₂epó (“from, off”)) + *ana (from Proto-Indo-European *h₂en- (“on”))*" und daher *Anfang* (*an* + *fangen*,  verwechselt mit *Angriff*?) und *Ende*, IE. *h₂ent- "front, face" verglichen werden, anhand derer deutlich wird, wie wirr bzw. unsicher das ganze ist.

Abschließend lässt sich sagen, dass es einfach logische ist, nur Zahlen zu nennen, an denen auch ein Interesse besteht. Bei großen Mengen macht es auch nur einen geringen Unterschied, zumal *zwischen sechs- und siebenhundert* oft als Schätzwert abgegeben wird.

Comment: Geographische Grenzen sind in der Regel sehr genau! Interessanter Artikel zu der Grenze zwischen Dänemark und Deutschland: https://geodaesie.info/zfv/heftbeitrag/215/zfv_2009_3_Gauss.pdf

Comment: Ich kenne da eher die Notationen [0,1) (von null bis eins) oder [0,1] (von null bis einschließlich eins), also eckige klammern für inklusiv und runde für exklusiv. Oder sogar [0, 1>, also mit "spitzen Klammern".

Answer (score 0):

Die Zweideutigkeit läßt sich leicht vermeiden, wenn man z. B. *Zahlen von Eins bis Sechs würfeln* schreibt.

Comment: *Von eins bis sechs* oder *von eins bis einschließlich sechs*? *Bis sechs* ist auch exklusiv sechs. Aber das wird auch oft falsch benutzt (ich vermute mal, du *meintest* von eins bis einschl. sechs).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis siehe den Link in meiner Antwort. *Urlaub vom 1. bis zum 6.* bedeutet *6 Tage frei*. Ob das in der Mathematik anders sein sollte, oder ob man dann genauer "bis ausschließlich" sagen müsste, bedürfte einer Authorität. Professoren sind aber oftmals recht authark. Der Duden wird sich in Fachsprache kaum einmischen. Das Einführungsbeispiel handelt m.M.n. eher weniger von Fachsprache.

Comment: @vectory: Wie ich schon sagte, wird das auch oft falsch gemacht. Danke für das Beispiel. Das hat nichts mit Mathematik zu tun.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis das würde ich sogar etwas überkritisch auch über das Einführungsbeispiel sagen. Da die Antwort darauf in beiden Lesarten wäre, "1/n (eins geteilt durch die Anzahl der Möglichkeiten)", und die Suche nach dem n nicht das Ziel der Übung, ist die sprachliche Genauigkeit für das Beispiel eigentlich schon ausreichend. Darüber kann man aber wie gesagt geteilter Meinung sein.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Ich bin da anderer Meinung. Von 1 bis 6 schließt die 6 ein.

Comment: @Martin: Ich weiß nicht,ob das von einer Meinung abhängt. Oder hast du auch eine Meinung über die Schwerkraft?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Ich weiß nicht, was die Bemerkung zu der Schwerkraft soll. Es ist einfach so: Wenn man schreibt _1, ..., n_, so liest man dies als _1 bis n_, und dann sind 1 und _n_ dabei. Wenn speziell _n = 6_ ist natürlich auch.

Comment: Ich meinte nur: eine Meinung ändert keine Tatsache, genauso wie eine Meinung über die Schwerkraft nichts ändert. Und wenn ich lese "1, ..., n" lese ich "eins bis einschießlich n". Das kann man anders lesen, aber dann macht man es eben falsch. Das wird ja oft falsch gemacht, wie ich schon sagte.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Ich habe bis jetzt noch keinen Mathematiker getroffen, der _1, ..., n_ als "eins bis einschließlich n" liest. Was Du als Tatsache propagierst, ist keine.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematisch auf Deutsch gleicht nicht Deutsch (e.g. mathematisch können Menge zugleich offen und abgeschlossen sein, was im Alltagsdeutsch absurd klingt).  Das gilt auch für Recht- und Musiksprache, usw.

Kein Mathematiker würde das ohne die Grenzpunkte verstehen. Das *zwischen* des Dudens **wird an reellen Zahlen modelliert**, bei deren Anwendung an der Realität wohl flexibler (verglichen mit ganzzahlige) in dem Sinne sind, dass man die Grenzpunkte gar nicht messen kann. Daher braucht man nicht unbedingt so präzis im Wörterbuch zu sein.

> *Beispiel.* In der Realität „kommt man zwischen 19 und 20 Uhr an“ bedeutet das Intervall (19,20)
>    oder [19,20] (ohne bzw. mit den Grenzpunkten), weil man keine haargenaue Uhr besitzen kann, die praktisch diese zwei Möglichkeiten unterscheidet.

Deine Situation ist **mit ganzzahligen und daher unterschiedlich**. Die Grenzwerte sind drin.

Mein Rat: beim Mathematik-Lernen, weg vom Duden. Die mathematische Sprache ist nicht vom Duden erfasst worden. Je fortgeschrittener dein mathematisches Kenntnis, desto abweichend dein Wortschatz von üblichen Wörterbüchern.