# Numerus des Prädikats bei zwei nachgestellten Subjekten, die mit "und/oder" verbunden sind

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunction, conjugation

Betrachten wir den Satz:

> Wenn wir die Funktion *f*(*x*,*y*) berechnen, **werden** in den rekursiven Aufrufen die gesamte Anzahl der Knoten in *x* und *y* und/oder die Länge der Sequenz *x* mit jedem Schritt kleiner.

Also ... **werden**? Oder doch **wird**?

Natürlich ist "A und/oder B" nicht standardsprachlich, bedeutet aber so viel wie "A oder B oder beides". Dies lässt die Frage jedoch nicht weniger spannend werden.

Laut [Helbig/Buscha 2013, §14] müsse man bei *Konjunktionen* (erst einmal ohne nähere Bestimmung, um welche Konjunktionen es sich dabei handelt) das finite Verb in den Plural setzen:

> Die Mutter und das Kind **warteten** auf dem Bahnsteig. Er und seine Frau **waren** im Urlaub.

Bei disjunktiven Konjunktionen stehe das Verb meist in Singular, es komme jedoch auch der Plural vor:

> Er oder sie **geht** heute einkaufen. Der Bruder oder die Schwester **fährt** in die Stadt. Zu der Feier **kommen** der Rektor oder ein Prorektor.

Also was tun bei "und/oder"?

Comment: Dieser User hat ca. 12 bis 20 seiner eigenen Posts vandalisiert, offenbar nach Meinungsverschiedenheiten mit e. Moderator. Ich habe die, die ich fand, zurückgerollt, nachdem ich anfänglich 3 als "Flag for moderator invention" markiert hatte. Rollback scheint mir nützlicher.

Answer (score 1):

Die Verwendung von Singular oder Plural kann davon abhängen, ob es sich um ein inklusives oder exklusives (entweder-) Oder handelt.

In dem Satz

> Er oder sie geht heute einkaufen.

deutet die Verwendung des Singulars darauf hin, dass **entweder** er **oder** sie heute einkaufen geht.

In dem Satz

> Zu der Feier kommen der Rektor oder ein Prorektor.

könnte die Verwendung des Plurals darauf hindeuten, dass **entweder** der Rektor **oder** ein Prorektor **oder** beide zur Feier kommen.

Während für die Konjunktion *und* der Plural zwingend ist, gilt für *oder*: Geschmackssache! Es gibt keine bindende Regel für die Genauigkeit einer Aussage und damit hier auch keine bindende Regel für die Verwendung von Singular oder Plural.

In mathematischen Texten ist das ein völlig anderes Problem.

Da `*und/oder*` in

> ... die gesamte Anzahl der Knoten in x und y und/oder die Länge der Sequenz x

letztlich heißt `(A oder B) oder (A und B)`, würde ich unbedingt **werden** verwenden.

Mathematische Sachverhalte erklärende Texte stellen den Autor grundsätzlich vor das Problem, in erster Linie sprachlichen Regeln folgen und gleichzeitig mathematische Begriffe von gleichlautenden standardsprachlichen Wörtern unterscheidbar halten zu müssen. Das stellt hohe Anforderungen an sowohl die mathematische als auch die sprachliche Kompetenz des Autors.

Mathematisch logische Konjunktionen und standardsprachliche Wörter der Wortart Konjunktion unterscheiden sich in ihren Bedeutungen. Der Oder-Operator als mathematischer Begriff muss als solcher gekennzeichnet werden, um Verwechslungen mit dem standardsprachlichen *oder* auszuschließen. Die mathematisch logische Bedeutung kann in erklärendem Fließtext (im Gegensatz zu Beweisen) nicht stillschweigend unterstellt werden. In Fließtexten überschneiden sich sprachlicher und mathematischer Geltungsbereich. Eine mathematische Aussage ist aber stets nur innerhalb eines spezifischen Geltungsbereiches beweisbar. Es ist mehr als fraglich, ob die Verwendung des Plurals hier allein ausreichend für die Korrektheit der Aussage wäre.

Das mathematisch logische *oder* `(A v B)` liefert folgende Wahrheitswerte:

```
| A | B | A v B |
|---|---|-------|
| 0 | 0 | 0     |
| 0 | 1 | 1     |
| 1 | 0 | 1     |
| 1 | 1 | 1     |

0 - falsch
1 - wahr
```

`(A v B)` ist also wahr, wenn **mindestens** eine der Aussagen wahr ist. Im standardsprachlich verwendeten Wort *oder* ist die Bedeutung der letzten Zeile - nämlich der Fall, dass beide Aussagen wahr sind - nicht zwingend enthalten.

Dasselbe gilt für die Konjunktion *und*. Im mathematisch logischen Sinn ist *und* nur dann wahr, wenn alle in Relation gesetzen Aussagen wahr sind. Für das standardsprachliche *und* gilt das nicht.

> Kinder und Renter haben freien Eintritt.

Das dürfte nur selten die Bedeutung haben, dass man Kind **und** Rentner sein muss, um nicht zahlen zu müssen.

Mathematisch ausgedrückt könnte das Gemeinte z.B. so aussehen:

`F := Personen, die freien Eintritt genießen`

`R := Rentner`

`K := Kinder`

`∀f∈F: f∈R v f∈K`

Es ist hier eindeutig, dass eine Bedingung genügt aber beide möglich sind. (Auch Kinder, die eine Waisenrente beziehen, haben freien Eintritt.)

Die Klarstellung im Fallbeispiel der Frage ist aus mathematischer Sicht korrekt, aus sprachlicher Sicht aber m.E. ungeschickt gelöst, auch wenn [der Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/und_oder) *und/oder* ausweist. Ich hätte aus stilistischen und didaktischen Gründen wohl eher

> werden ... die gesamte Anzahl der Knoten in x und y oder (inkl.) die Länge der Sequenz x ... kleiner

oder

> werden ... die gesamte Anzahl der Knoten in x und y oder die Länge der Sequenz x oder beide ... kleiner

verwendet, in jedem Fall aber ** werden **.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematisch ist die Verwendung von "und/oder" unkorrekt, da das mathematische "oder" auch "A und B" umfaßt.

Im Umgangsdeutsch ist die Feststellung, daß A (eine Anzahl) kleiner wird und daß B (eine Länge) auch kleiner wird, wie in der Fundstelle angegeben, zusammenfassend mit Pluralbildung zu beschreiben. Beide werden kleiner bzw. schrumpfen. Wer das nicht mag, schreibt:
"Der rekursive Aufruf von f(x,y) mindert die Knotenzahl in x und y oder die Sequenzlänge x."

Comment: @user49915: Mein inkorrektes "unkorrekt" deutet an, daß ich unschlüssig bin, ob in mathematischer Notation Überflüssiges inkorrekt und damit falsch ist. Danke für die dezente Korrektur.

Answer (score -1):

In deinem ersten Satz bezieht sich *wird* auf "...die .. Anzahl" und ist somit zweifelsfrei Singular, auch wenn die Anzahl häufiger auftritt.

Es gibt die KNG-Kongruenz (Kasus, Numerus, Genus), heißt: dein Verb muss genau die KNG-Eigenschaften haben wie dein(e) Nomen, auf das/die es sich bezieht. Hast du nur eins - easy. Sind es mehrere, kannst du alle zusammen (Plural) beschreiben oder aber den Singular verwenden, sofern jedes einzelne Nomen in Kasus, Genus und Numerus mit dem Verb übereinstimmt.

Also:
Eine direkte Aufzählung hat den Plural zur Folge: *Er und sie und sonstwer sind im Urlaub.* 
Aber ein nachgestellter Satzeinschub oder Nebensatz lässt den Singular zu:
*Er ist im Urlaub und sie auch.*

Oder meint eines der durch das Wort oder getrennten Worte, also immer Singular. Er oder sie **ist** und nicht **sind** [Adjektiv hier einfügen]

Und hingegen meint eine Gruppe von Sachen und hat den Plural zur Folge. Er und sie **sind** [whatever]