# Der Bruder, dann die Schwester kam(en) um die Ecke

Tags: grammatical-number

Muss das Verb im folgenden Satz in den Plural oder in den Singular?

> Der Bruder, dann die Schwester kam(en) um die Ecke.

Comment: Related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/50154/1696).

Comment: Nein, die verlinkte Frage hat mit dieser nichts zu tun. In meiner Frage gibt es keine Konjunktion! Siehe meine Antwort.

Comment: Dass deine Antwort als erstes Beispiel eine Konjunktion verwendet, und sei es auch nur zur Abgrenzung, bestätigt aber den Zusammenhang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mit *und* wird das Subjekt erweitert *(Der Bruder und die Schwester ...)*, mit *dann* dagegen wird ein neuer Satz begonnen. Letztlich wird im ersten Satz das Prädikat ausgelassen *(Der Bruder kam, dann kam die Schwester.)*.

Die grammatische Struktur wird an diesem Beispiel deutlich:

> 1. *Paul und Peter kommen.*
> 2. a. <strike>*Paul kommen, dann Peter.*</strike>
>    b. *Paul kommt, dann [kommt] Peter.*
>    c. *Paul kommt, dann geht Peter.*

Im ersten Beispiel handeln beide Personen gemeinsam. Als ein erweitertes Subjekt führen sie eine einzelne Handlung aus. Dies wird durch das *und* ausgedrückt. Im zweiten Beispiel dagegen handeln beide Personen unabhängig voneinander. Dass beide nun zufälligerweise dieselbe Handlung ausführen ist grammatisch irrelevant, wie die Variante mit zwei unterschiedlichen Prädikaten (2c) zeigt.

Der Unterschied zwischen *Der Bruder kam um die Ecke, dann die Schwester* und *Der Bruder, dann die Schwester kam um die Ecke* ist ein stilistischer. Im ersten Fall entsteht die Vorstellung, dass der Bruder vollständig um die Ecke herumgekommen ist, bevor die Schwester erscheint, während im zweiten Fall nicht nur im Satzbau, sondern dadurch auch in unserer Vorstellung der Abstand zwischen Bruder und Schwester verringert wird und diese gewissermaßen lückenlos aufeinander zu folgen scheinen.

Answer (score 3):

Der Hauptsatz lautet:

> Der Bruder *kam* um die Ecke.

Das Verb steht hier in der dritten Person Singular. Die [grammatische Person](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person_(Grammatik)) ändert sich auch nicht durch Anfügen oder Einschieben eines [Beisatzes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition), wie

> dann die Schwester

der als solcher mit Komma(s) vom Hauptsatz abgetrennt wird. Ist er am Ende angefügt, genügt ein Komma; ist er eingeschoben, wird er mit paarigen Kommas abgetrennt:

> Der Bruder *kam* um die Ecke, dann die Schwester.
>
> Der Bruder, dann die Schwester, *kam* um die Ecke.

Comment: Du meinst wohl dritte Person _Singular_

Comment: Auf welcher Grundlage betrachtest Du _dann die Schwester_ als Apposition? Der Wiki-Link führt aus, dass Appositionen das Bezugswort näher beschreiben. _Der Bruder, der Sohn ihrer Mutter, kam um die Ecke_ wäre ein klares Beispiel dafür. Aber es fällt mir schwer, _dann die Schwester_ als Apposition zu verstehen. Es scheint mir eher eine Art von [Konjunktion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktion_(Wortart)#Nebenordnende_Konjunktionen_im_Deutschen) zu sein, wobei das _und_ fehlt. In diesem Fall müsste auch das Verb im Plural stehen: _Der Bruder [und] dann die Schwester kamen um die Ecke_.

Comment: Die Hauptsätze (!) lauten: *Der Bruder kam.* und *Die Schwester kam.* Beide Ereignisse finden nacheinander statt (ausgedrückt durch *dann*) und werden von den beiden Subjekten unabhängig voneinander ausgeführt. Siehe meine Antwort.

Comment: @fluctuatingpsychosis, das mit dem Nacheinander der Ereignisse ist ein guter Hinweis.

Answer (score 3):

Ich sehe das folgendermaßen:

In diesem Fall haben wir zwei Personen, die "kamen". Dh. den Bruder und die Schwester kann man als Konjunktion ansehen, weshalb hier auch Plural verwendet werden sollte:

> Der Bruder, dann die Schwester kamen um die Ecke.

Anders wäre es, wenn man die Schwester ans Ende des Satzes verschieben würde:

> Der Bruder kam um die Ecke, dann die Schwester.

Da im Beispiel aber beide Personen vor dem Verb stehen, sollte hier auch die Mehrzahl des Verbs verwendet werden.

Comment: Die beiden Personen werden aber nicht mit einer Konjunktion (wie *und*) verbunden, deshalb kann man sie auch nicht als Konjunktion ansehen.

Answer (score 0):

Plural sollte es sein. Der Bruder, dann die Schwester kamen um die Ecke. Aber die Satzkonstruktion ist eher ungewöhnlich.

Wer kam? Der Bruder und die Schwester kamen um die Ecke. Es sind ja zwei Personen. Das der eine zuerst kommt und dann der Andere, das ist ja egal. Sind trotzdem zwei. Du sagst ja auch „Das Auto und das Motorrad stehen / standen in der Garage.“ nicht „Das Auto und das Motorrad steht in der Garage.@

Comment: Dass der eine zuerst kommt und dann der andere ist gerade nicht egal. Denn dadruch handeln beide nicht mehr gemeinsam, sondern jeder für sich. Siehe meine Antwort.

Comment: Sehr überzeugend und super Antwort. Upvote. Und danke für die Korrektur.

Answer (score 0):

Es ist ganz einfach beides möglich.

Im Allgemeinen steht zwar bei mehrteiligen Subjekten und einer Aufzählung das Verb im Plural, aber wenn die Bestandteile des mehrteiligen Subjekts alle im Singular stehen, *kann* das Verb auch im Singular stehen.

Leo hat dazu eine ziemlich lange [Abhandlung](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wort/Verb/Kategorien/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html?lang=de&lang=de#id=1.3.2.2.c.2a).

Comment: Es ist kein mehrteiliges Subjekt, es sind zwei Subjekte. Siehe meine Antwort.